# Как сделать, чтобы команда в aiogram заработала в боте?

Tags: python, aiogram

Хочу написать бота и мне нужно, чтобы после ввода пароля срабатывала команда /number. После ввода этой команды человек будет вводить номер телефона и программа будет уже обрабатывать его

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import StatesGroup, State

import config

TOKEN = "mytoken"
bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)


class FSMInputName(StatesGroup):
    name = State()


@dp.message_handler(commands=["start"])
async def process_start_command(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Чтобы войти, введите команду /password")


@dp.message_handler(commands=["password"])
async def cmd_pass(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("Введите пароль")
    await FSMInputName.name.set()


@dp.message_handler(state=FSMInputName.name)
async def state_pass(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['password'] = message.text
        if message.text == "hkpo123":
            await message.answer("Введите команду /number, чтобы ввести номер клиента")

            @dp.message_handler(commands=["number"])
            async def cmd_num(message1: types.Message):
                await message1.answer("Введите номер")
                await FSMInputName.name.set()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверьте, в таком виде должен получиться желаемый результат. Команда `/number` была убрана и получение номера перенесено в FSM

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import StatesGroup, State

import config

TOKEN = "mytoken"
bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)


class FSMInputName(StatesGroup):
    password = State()
    phone = State()


@dp.message_handler(commands=["start"])
async def process_start_command(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Чтобы войти, введите команду /password")


@dp.message_handler(commands=["password"])
async def cmd_pass(message: types.Message):
    await FSMInputName.password.set()
    await message.answer("Введите пароль")


@dp.message_handler(state=FSMInputName.password)
async def state_pass(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    if message.text == "hkpo123":
        async with state.proxy() as data:
            data['password'] = message.text
        await FSMInputName.phone.set()
        await message.answer("Введите номер клиента")
    else:
        await message.answer("Вы ввели неверный пароль. Введите команду /password, чтобы попробовать еще раз")
        await state.finish()

@dp.message_handler(state=FSMInputName.phone)
async def cmd_phone(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await message.answer(f"Вы ввели номер {message.text}") # Тут вы можете обрабатывать номер телефона
    await state.finish()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает, и я так понимаю что пихать асинхр функцию внутрь такой же другой не очень хорошая идея, это я про себя. Но мне надо сделать, чтобы была команда /number, так как вводов номеров будет много, это как бы для магазина надо чтобы часто добавлять номера клиентов в БД. И допустим для каждого магазина есть свой пароль и когда он его вводит и если пароль правильный то последующие ввода номеров будут идти именно в базу данных именно этого магазина, к кому приаттачен данный пароль. Подключать и записывать в базу данных у меня проблем нет. Буду признателен за помощь

Comment: в таком случае правильнее будет сделать так: запрашиваете пароль - если пароль верный, то записываете `id` в базу как разрешенный - пишите функцию `/number`, которая будет выполняться только для разрешенных `id`. Либо, если вы точно знаете список тех, кто будет писать, то можно функционал с вводом пароля убрать и просто ограничиться подготовленным списком с разрешенными `id`

Comment: ID Вы имеете ввиду userID телеграмовский?

Comment: да, `user_id/chat_id`

Comment: Понял, спасибо, буду пробовать