# Как сделать ожидание ответа от пользователя aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram, бот

Бот при отправке команды /start выводит сообщение 'Отправьте следующим сообщением ваш номер телефона для связи с вами', далее, по идее, он должен ждать любой текст от пользователя. Как
это должно работать: Сообщение бота -> Бот ожидает сообщение от пользователя -> Пользователь отправляет сообщение -> Сообщение принимается ботом и сохраняется.

Я пытался найти что то похожее, но оно не работает. Помогите пожалуйста.
Вот неработающий код:

P.S. Нашел решение путем добавления класса и изменение состояния.

```
async def order(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply('Отправьте следующим сообщением ваш номер телефона для связи с вами')

@dp.message_handler(Text())
async def handle_message(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    text = message.text
    print(text)
    await message.reply('Спасибо, мы с вами свяжемся')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: [Вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1520035/479903) вы можете найти решение своего вопроса